# What's a more formal equivalent to "seriously out of line"?

Tags: word-choice, formality

What is a more formal equivalent to "seriously out of line"? In the particular case I'm looking for, I've been advised that what I'm referring to is seriously out of line *legally*, but the question is general.

Comment: Why not just **forbidden**?

Comment: Are you talking about bad behavior? Flouting the law? Violence? Harassment? Stalking? More context would help.

Comment: I'm looking for a general term or phrase, not specific to the legal context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In everyday, non-legal language, "beyond the pale" is probably the best match. But it's hard to say, when you've given no context.

Answer (score 1):

Simply **unacceptable**. Or **totally unacceptable** (the adjective-modifier is really the equivalent of an exclamation mark here, purely pragmatic).

Answer (score 0):

How about

> Extremely illegal ?

Although there's allegedly no grey areas in the law, so "illegal" might even do the job you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**"wrong"** fits the bill. This is the word that "out of line" is trying to avoid saying.

Answer (score 0):

I think **woefully inappropriate** fits the meaning exactly.